# Create two different arrays in php and show the combined result

Tags: php, arrays

suppose,

```
$name = array("raj","ram","pooja");
$rel = array("brother","father","sister");

Array (
         [0] => raj 
         [1] => ram 
         [2] => pooja
      )

 Array ( 
        [0] => Brother 
        [1] => father 
)
```

output show as like follows

```
ram => raj
```

and on arrow between 2 name brother keyword must be display from 2nd array.. in short output must show as like the relationship between 2 array... first array consist name and 2nd array consist its relationship. please tell me

Comment: Your question is bit vague but I guess what you need is `array_combine($name,$rel)` ?

Comment: do you want to say like ravi's brother is raj.but none of the array has value ravi. so plz update your question with correct value.

Comment: sorry its not ravi its ram and ram is borther of raj

Comment: so you want like ram brother is raj  and ram is father of pooja ?

Comment: Try my editted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $name=array("raj","ram","pooja"); $rel=array("brother","father");

$array=array();

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($name);$i++)
{
    if($i<(sizeof($name)-1)) {
         echo "".$name[$i]." ".$rel[$i]." ".$name[$i+1]."<br>";
        $arrays = $name[$i]." ".$rel[$i]." ".$name[$i+1];
        array_push($array, $arrays);
    }

}

print_r($array);
```

**Note:** this will not display relationship over `=>`. instead it replaces that symbol by relationship

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/6MAfH)